# How to use like operator in Presto with string that contain a dot?

Tags: presto, trino

I have a column string like this

"test.123.test"
"something"

And I want run a query to find string like "test.*.test". In postgresql I use this query:

`select * from table where string_column like 'test.%.test'`

I run this query in presto but got nothing! It should be related to dot in my string because when I replace string like with something like this 'test.1%1.test' it work but it's not my result.

Comment: I know I can use regexp_like("string_column", 'test..*.test'), but like operator not work.

Comment: It's PostgreSQL connector's bug. Please take a look at https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/3645

Comment: Are you running the query against presto or against via presto against a postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Presto query

```
string_column like 'test.%.test'
```

the predicate pushed down into the PostgreSQL connector is similar to:

```
string_column BETWEEN 'test.' AND 'test/'
```

however, string comparison are subject to collation and trailing punctuations hits an edge case of Presto/PostgreSQL incompatibility: https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/3645

You can **workaround** this by preventing predicate pushdown into the connector. You can achieve this by adding `OR rand() = 42` to your query:

```
string_column like 'test.%.test' OR rand() = 42
```